# Distributing in-memory linked list

Tags: linked-list, architecture

I have a program which is build based on a singly linked list. There are different programs which creates some form of data and this data sent to this linked list module to be added. As long as I've RAM available, program working as intended. Periodically -about every year-, I archive the entire linked list to the disk -due to requirement, I'm archiving all-. So far so good.

What happens if I wanted to add new node to the list whilst RAM is full and I haven't archived and freed the memory on RAM? This might occur when producer count goes up or regardless of producer count, there may be more data created depending or where it's used etc. I couldn't find a clear solution the scale the on-memory linked list. There is a workaround in my head but don't know even if it works so I thought better to ask here.

1. When the RAM start to get almost full, I would create a new instance
   of the linked list program -just another machine on the cloud or new
   physical computer on premise, whatever -.
2. I do have an service discovery module -something like ZooKeeper-, this discovery module will detect the newly created machine and adds to the list.
3. When first instance is almost in it's limits, it will check if there is an available instance, if there is; it will relay the node to the next instance and it will update its last node's next pointer to something special. If you wanted to traverse the list from start to finish across all the machines every time you come to this special node, it will have the information of the which machine has the next node. Traversal will continue from the next machine that the last node points to.

Since this this not a hash map or something in that nature, I can't just add replicate the service and for example relay the incoming request based on a given key to a particular machine.

Rather than archiving part of the old data and loading that to the RAM and continuing on like that, I thought it would be better to have a last pointer to point to a different machine and continue reading from that machine. My choice for a network call seemed better because this program will be used in a intranet, but still I couldn't find a solid solution on paper.

Is there a such example that I can study on and try to find a better solution? Is this solution feasible?

An example:

```
Machine 1:
 1st node : [data:x, *next: 2nd Node address],
 2nd node : [data:123, *next: 3rd Node address],
 ...
 // at this point RAM is almost full
 // receive next instance's ip
 (n-1)th node :  [data:987, *next: nth Node address],
 nth node : [data:x2t, type: LastNodeInMachine, *next: nullptr]

Machine 2:
 1st node == (n+1) node : [data:x, *next: 2nd Node address],
 ... and so on
```

Comment: what happens to the data in the list?

Comment: There is no editing or doing computation with the data. It's just there to be read in the future. That's why I put random numbers on the example

Comment: why not archive it as soon as it comes in?

Comment: @user253751 , it's archived as soon as node is inserted for persistency but since data is heavily read it's crucial for them to stay on the RAM during execution of the program.

Comment: Did you know there are systems like Apache Kafka which do this kind of thing automatically? (I don't know very much about Kafka so it is possible that it doesn't do what you want)

Comment: @user253751 I'm aware of them :) This is my own implementation of a Kafka-like system. That's how I implemented my service discovery system, by looking at ZooKeeper which Kafka uses

Comment: then, sure, I suppose you could do something like this idea. It's probably not ideal because I bet you don't really need so much data in RAM.